# Why does my site look like garbage in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Davey Whitney</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://daveywhitney.com/images/favicon.ico" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"><!--mce:0--></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!--mce:1--></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jparallax.js" type="text/javascript"><!--mce:2--></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 



<meta name="keywords" content="Davey Whitney,Davey,Whitney,Web Designer,Web Design,Web Development,Web" />
<meta name="description" content="Davey Whitney - Web Developer and so much more..." />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#parallax')
    .animate(
{duration: '2000', easing: 'easeInSine'

    })
    .jparallax({yparallax:false},{xtravel: '100%'},{xtravel: '300px'});
});



</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="icons">
    <a href="mailto:davey@daveywhitney.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://daveywhitney.com/images/gmail.png" border="0" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/davey-whitney/15/a15/86a" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://daveywhitney.com/images/linkedin.png" border="0" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/daveywhitney" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://daveywhitney.com/images/twitter.png" border="0" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#/profile.php?ref=profile&id=13810754" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://daveywhitney.com/images/facebook.png" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>


<div id="copyright">

&copy; <a href="mailto:davey@daveywhitney.com" target="_blank">Davey Whitney</a>

</div>

<div id="parallax"> 
<img style="width: 61px;" src="http://daveywhitney.com/images/merun.png" alt="" />
</div>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-12009950-2");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    width:1200px;
}

#icons {

    padding:100px 0 0 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:530px;
    border:0;   
}

#copyright {
    width:150px;
    margin:50px auto;
}

#copyright a:link {
    color: #3F7BCA;
}

#copyright a:hover {
    color: #F28900;
}

a  {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#parallax
    {
    position:relative; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:100%; 
    height:98px;
    border:none;
    margin:0 auto 20px auto; 
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Here is the site: http://daveywhitney.com/

Comment: Can you define "garbage"?  This is subjective.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say was "Why doesn't my site look like it should in IE"

Comment: How should it look?  Can you provide specific examples, maybe some screen shots?

Comment: When does a site *not* look like garbage in IE? :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because it's rendering in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) - IE doesn't like **anything** before the DOCTYPE. Remove the comment and it should render in **standards mode** (his live site contained a large comment before the DOCTYPE which isn't visible in the question).

From Wikipedia:

> Quirks mode in any version of IE will
>   also be triggered if anything but
>   whitespace precedes the DOCTYPE. For
>   example, if a hypertext document
>   contains a comment or any tag before
>   the DOCTYPE, IE will use quirks mode:
>
> ```
> <!-- This comment will put IE 6, 7 and 8 in quirks mode -->
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> ```

Comment: Wow, I removed the comment from my index page and it looks perfect. I had no idea that could possibly be a problem.

Comment: Also, I put the comment after the doctype and everything was still fine. I can still have my obnoxious ascii art if I want. Hooray!

Comment: Just a thought: Will whitespace count as anything before the doctype declaration?

Comment: @alex: Nope, whitespace is fine - but *only* whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about IE6, then it is because IE6 is an outdated browser that doesn't support many common html and css tools.

Comment: IE7. Should I just not even care about people using IE?

Comment: If your analytics are similar to mine, you probably get about as much traffic from IE as you do from FF.

Comment: @Davey: That's a question you need to ask yourself. "Who is my audience". "Am I losing business (or whatever) but ignoring users who use (possible not by choice) IE".

Comment: You should care about IE users.  they make up the majority of internet users.  IE 7 and 8 are "modern" browsers.  IE 6 should be discontinued.

Comment: In my experience, getting a site to work in IE is a major headache, but I guess it maximizes your audience.

Comment: Got it to work in IE but this is an incredibly simple site, why must we be tormented like this?

Comment: The boys up in Redmond are rather sadistic. I would recommend using the W3C standards validator if your site ever starts acting weird again: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Kyle,
IE7/8 are NOT modern browsers. Modern browsers can do better than DOM Level 1. They can handle XHTML served as XHTML as well as SVG, MathML, the current javascript standard. Modern browsers move forward with new implementations like canvas, video and audio. Modern browsers don't have tens of web sites dedicated to fixing them alone and don't have developers crying for them to support the standard. People complain about IE9s shortcomings and it's not even out yet. Modern browser vendors don't join standards committees (SVG) 10 years late.

No version of IE is a "modern browser".

Answer (score 1):

Because IE is obviously garbage...IE6 at least, IE8 is pretty good.
Make sure you aren't using any CSS3 features, Opera is the only one that supports most of that. Also, validate your page, if you fix the issues it finds, most of your problems will probably be resolved.